# Built-in Generic Types

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I read somewhere that EventHandler is a built-in generic type. Why is that so? Could somebody explain me ways to distinguish between generic and non-generic types?

Thanks,
Abhi.

================

I am reading Microsoft .NET Framework Application Development Foundation 2nd edition to prepare for MCTS. In the first chapter, there was a question as below:-

Which of the following are examples of built-in generic types? (Choose all that
apply.)
A. Nullable
B. Boolean
C. EventHandler
D. System.Drawing.Point

The answer of the question is A and C as per the book. Option A is alright, but wasn't sure about option C. Can somebody please explain?

Comment: "EventHandler is a built-in generic type" - in what language?

Comment: What programming language? What did you read?

Comment: Tim/Peter, I have updated my original post. The language is C#.

Comment: How can I not choose more than one answer as accepted answer? Most of you have answered my answer in your own way and I want to mark at least 2 of them as accepted answer!! Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question you ultimately need to look up each type name in the MSDN index. Nullable appears as `Nullable<T>`. `EventHandler` shows up twice, with and without the `<T>` suffix. These are in fact separate types.

Comment: Nullable also exists without the `<T>`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There are two types: [`EventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx) and [`EventHandler<TEventArgs>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx). Obviously the first isn't generic, and the second is.

Comment: There is a [third EventHandler](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/EventHandler.html) as well :) Less related to generics though.

Comment: By looking at <T>, I can say that it is generic, but if you see the question that I have posted in my original post (updated a few minutes ago), it doesn't mention <T>. Is it that the quesion was not asked properly or is it that just by the name of type, we can make out whether it is generic or not?

Comment: @user366436: Both Nullable and EventHandler exist in generic and non-generic forms. It seems to me it's just a bad question.

Answer (score 0):

T is the type of EventArgs the eventhanlder handles (so `T : EventArgs`)

Answer (score 0):

In C# (but it applies to Java too), you can recognize generics by the presence of *Type Parameters*, usually indicated between `<>` brackets.

For example, the generic type of EventHandler in C# is declared as:

```
public delegate void EventHandler<TEventArgs>(object sender, TEventArgs e);
```

The type `TEventArgs` that parameterises the delegate is used to have static typing inside the event handler function, without the need for casts or to define multiple delegate types for each type of argument you need passed to the handler.

Say you have 2 different events, one generating objects of type `T1`, one of type `T2`.
You will have two different handlers:

```
void HandleEvent1(object sender, T1 args) {...}
void HandleEvent2(object sender, T2 args) {...}
```

In C# 1.0 (no generics) you would create your own delegate types for the 2 events:

```
delegate void Event1Handler(object sender, T1 e);
delegate void Event2Handler(object sender, T2 e);
```

And use them to bind your event with the handlers.

From C# 2.0 there's no need to create new delegate types, since both handlers are captured by the generic `EventHandler<>` type (`TEventArgs` = `T1` or `TEventArgs` = `T2`).

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28VS.80%29.aspx) for an intro on generics.

Answer (score 0):

The question is badly phrased, but is asking which of the types are generic (or have generic versions). The answer is [`EventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx) and [`Nullable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx), since [`Boolean`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.aspx) and [`Point`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.aspx) do not have generic equivalents.